# model.predict () return an array instead of a number/label

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to used a trained model to predict `model.predict(data)` a new testing data for classification. However, instead of a number/label, the program returns an array. How to modify my training code to get the output correctly? Thank you. Here is my code.

```
def make_model(input_shape):
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=150, kernel_size=100, padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv1)

    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=150, kernel_size=100, padding="same")(conv1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv2)

    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=150, kernel_size=100, padding="same")(conv2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv3)

    gap = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(conv3)

    output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(gap)

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)


model = make_model(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:])
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

epochs = 400
batch_size = 16

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        "best_model.h5", save_best_only=True, monitor="val_loss"
    ),
    keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=20, min_lr=0.0001
    ),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=50, verbose=1),
]
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
)
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_split=0.2,
    verbose=1,
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sagi, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is performing as expected. Your last layer is calculated using softmax, and produces an array with probabilities of how "sure" it is of being each label.

If you want to get the actual predicted label, you can use `argmax`, along with the correct dimension, which returns the index(=label) that had the maximum probability.  In any typical fit function, you can normally see that the accuracy is being calculated using `argmax` on the output of the model.